# Will an electron gun fire behind it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

If an electron travels as a wave, can it therefore not be aimed with any precision?

If you fire an electron gun, can't you aim it at a particular slit?

If the electron travels as a wave, will an electron gun hit anything at a 180 degree angle from the barrel? 360 degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrons are not waves. Neither are they little dots of matter. The wave/particle duality means that *some* properties of electrons are as if they are a wave, and *some* are as if they are particles. They are neither, and they "travel" exactly as the hybrid quantum object they are: Unless they interact with something, they do not take on any definite trajectory.

When you "fire" an electron gun, you create an electron state that is quite sharp inside a momentum interval $[p,p + \Delta p]$, and therefore, by the [Heisenberg uncertainty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_uncertainty) rather diffuse in position $[x, x +\Delta x]$. Broadly speaking, the electron will be able to reach all positions $y$ that can be reached from any of the positions inside $[x, x + \Delta x]$ with any of the momenta inside $[p,p + \Delta p]$.

Quantum mechanically, the object that tells you how likely it is to find a particle at $y$ given you know it was at $x$ a definite time $t$ before is called the [propagator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator). The momentum you give the electron defines a set of position states the electron is initially distributed across, and calculating the propagator for each of these states (with the proper prefactor as given in the initial distribution) for a given target position $y$ will yield the probability to find the fired electron at $y$.

But the important thing is that quantum objects *do not travel* in the classical sense. They have (discounting Bohmian interpretations) no trajectory to speak of, they simply have probabilities to be found at $y$ after they were found at $x$.

On classical scales, the distributions of position and momenta are so sharp that the uncertainty is neglegible, and therefore, on sufficiently large scales, you could speak of "aiming" an electron gun.